# R: unable to save an element of a object

Tags: r, save

I am attempting to save an object, but it fails:

```
> save("MEs", "moduleColors", "net$dendrograms", file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")
Error in save("MEs", "moduleColors", "net$dendrograms", file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData") : 
  object ‘net$dendrograms’ not found
> save(list=c("MEs", "moduleColors", "net$dendrograms"), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")
Error in save(list = c("MEs", "moduleColors", "net$dendrograms"), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData") : 
  object ‘net$dendrograms’ not found
> save(list=c(MEs, moduleColors, net$dendrograms), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid first argument
> save(MEs, moduleColors, as.vector(net$dendrograms), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData") 
Error in save(MEs, moduleColors, as.vector(net$dendrograms), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData") : 
  object ‘as.vector(net$dendrograms)’ not found
> save(MEs, moduleColors, list(net$dendrograms), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")
Error in save(MEs, moduleColors, list(net$dendrograms), file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData") : 
  object ‘list(net$dendrograms)’ not found
> head(net$dendrograms)
[[1]]

Call:
fastcluster::hclust(d = as.dist(dissTom), method = "average")
...
> ls(net)
 [1] "blockGenes"     "blocks"         "colors"         "dendrograms"   
 [5] "goodGenes"      "goodSamples"    "MEs"            "MEsOK"         
 [9] "TOMFiles"       "unmergedColors"
```

I can access it and I can save it with saveRDS:

```
> saveRDS(net$dendrograms, "dendro")
>
```

Or I can save it with:

```
> tmp <- list(net$dendrograms)
> save(MEs, moduleColors, tmp, file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")
>
```

Why I can't save the object as expected with `save(MEs, moduleColors, net$dendrograms, file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")` ?

The sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] WGCNA_1.51            RSQLite_1.0.0         DBI_0.4-1            
[4] fastcluster_1.1.20    dynamicTreeCut_1.63-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5           RColorBrewer_1.1-2    GenomeInfoDb_1.4.3   
 [4] plyr_1.8.4            iterators_1.0.8       tools_3.2.3          
 [7] rpart_4.1-10          preprocessCore_1.30.0 gtable_0.2.0         
[10] lattice_0.20-33       Matrix_1.2-6          foreach_1.4.3        
[13] parallel_3.2.3        gridExtra_2.2.1       cluster_2.0.4        
[16] S4Vectors_0.6.6       IRanges_2.2.9         stats4_3.2.3         
[19] grid_3.2.3            nnet_7.3-12           impute_1.42.0        
[22] Biobase_2.28.0        data.table_1.9.6      AnnotationDbi_1.30.1 
[25] survival_2.39-4       foreign_0.8-66        latticeExtra_0.6-28  
[28] Formula_1.2-1         GO.db_3.1.2           ggplot2_2.1.0        
[31] Hmisc_3.17-4          scales_0.4.0          codetools_0.2-14     
[34] matrixStats_0.50.2    splines_3.2.3         BiocGenerics_0.14.0  
[37] colorspace_1.2-6      acepack_1.3-3.3       doParallel_1.0.10    
[40] munsell_0.4.3         chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: try save(MEs, moduleColors, as.vector(net$dendrograms, file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")

Comment: @CClaire Done unsuccessfully, and edited to the question

Comment: Maybe use tmp <- list(net$dendrograms); save(MEs, moduleColors, tmp, file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")

Comment: @CClaire Unexpectedly worked. I will rephrase the question, to understand this behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this problem myself too. I don't know why, but the `save` command from `base` is only capable of saving 'whole' objects. Saving only a column of a data frame is not possible (to the best of my knowledge). My workaround would be:

```
netDendongrams <- net$dendogrames
save("MEs", "moduleColors", "netDendongrams ", file = "TNF_AH-network-auto.RData")
```

Comment: This is exactly what @CClaire  answer in the coment.

Comment: Not exactly as MarcelG don't use the list and explains better the specificities of the function save

Comment: @ChristopheD. Sorry, that comment wasn't there yet (or I did not see it) when i was writing my answer

Comment: Once I read the title of OP's question I realized the problem was I was saving an element, not a whole object. Your solution is exactly what I had already done by the time I read your solution, so it must be pretty good!